# How to make random unlimited terrain in a pyglet side scroller?

Tags: python, pyglet

I am trying to make a side scroller game using pyglet and I have managed to draw a background, a character and some terrain. (I am pretty new to GUI stuff) The problem is that when the player moves the character, the terrain is meant to generate itself (like games like terraria) but I can't find a way to do it without making 1000 copies of a sprite. Do you have any ideas on how I would go about this? Feel free to ask questions if I haven't made myself clear :)

EDIT: What I've been doing so far is creating a variable for each terrain like this:

```
ground_1 = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ground1, x=-100, y=200, batch = terrain)
ground = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ground1, 0, y=200, batch = terrain)
ground2 = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ground1, x=100, y = 200, batch = terrain)
ground3 = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ground1, x=200, y = 200, batch = terrain)
ground4 = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ground1, x=300, y = 200, batch = terrain)
ground5 = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ground1, x=400, y = 200, batch = terrain)
ground6 = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ground1, x=500, y = 200, batch = terrain)
ground7 = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ground1, x=600, y = 200, batch = terrain)
ground8 = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ground1, x=700, y = 200, batch = terrain)
ground9 = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ground1, x=800, y = 200, batch = terrain)
ground10 = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ground1, x=900, y = 200, batch = terrain)
```

I also created a class for seeing whether the block had a tree on it:

```
class block():
    """ block """
    def __init__(self,image,tree,grass,destroyed):
        self.image = image
        self.tree = tree
        self.grass = grass
        self.destroyed = destroyed

newGround1 = block(newGround,tree[treeR],grass[grassR],destroyed[destroyedR])

groundO = block(ground_1,False,False,False)
groundO1 = block(ground,True,False,False)
groundO2 = block(ground2,False,False,False)
groundO3 = block(ground3,False,False,False)
groundO4 = block(ground4,False,False,False)
groundO5 = block(ground5,False,False,False)
groundO6 = block(ground6,False,False,False)
groundO7 = block(ground7,False,False,False)
groundO8 = block(ground8,False,False,False)
groundO9 = block(ground9,False,False,False)
groundO10 = block(ground10,False,False,False)
```

But I was wondering if I had to create *ground2, ground3, ground4...* for all the terrain I want or if there is a simpler way of generating it (possibly unlimited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you should be able to store all these `ground` objects in a list rather than storing them.

```
#pseudocode
grounds_list = []
for x in range(0, 100000, 100):
   ground = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(ground1, x, y=200, batch = terrain) #x gets passed in here
   groundO1 = block(ground,True,False,False)
   grounds_list.append(ground) #store the objects you want to keep
```

So you'd iterated through this grounds_list when you need to find more stuff.